# 53.com US bank account blocked withdrawl

Tags: united-states, bank-account, withdrawal

I have opened this account on F1 visa(expired now) and was using it to receive consulting income for work done being in India for US clients. My money is stuck there.

They have not given me any timeline of when they will close the account and issue a check. I ask them if i can remit money to indian account. They didn't remove block on withdrawl. Can I sue then for blocking access to funds?

I have applied for B1 visa for which interview dates have not opened yet.

Can someone please suggest how to handle this situation?

Comment: Wat reason did they give for the block?

Comment: Your immigration status is not really relevant other than to whether you should file W8 or W9. If you filed W9 when you should have filed W8, or filed neither - that could explain the block.

Comment: @Aganju Status in usa expired few years ago. They need visa on file.

Comment: I have w8 which they said was rejected by their system as i have no status in usa i.e visa of file. @littleadv

Comment: @akash this makes no sense, W8 is specifically for non-residents.

Comment: I will call them today and ask the same question @littleadv

Comment: Have you had **any** payments via this method? Are you certain that the money exists?

Comment: I mean could this be a scam?

Comment: They opened access to the account and let me withdraw. Thanks everyone.